# ConcurrentModificationException on iteration through list, synchronized and using iterators

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, iterator

How is it possible to get a ConcurrentModificationException for this code-block?

```
synchronized (list) {
        for (Iterator<?> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            Object object = it.next();
            // do something to object without touching list
        }
}
```

Edit: sorry, that was not specific enough: // do something to object does not touch the list

Comment: Is the list an actual list or a wrapper? If it is a wrapper the lock would not be on the backing list itself.

Comment: +1 good point, but it's an actual list, no wrapper.

Comment: A for-each loop would be simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By having another thread modifying the list, for example.

Just because you synchronize this code block doesn't mean all the accesses to the list are blocked. It only makes sure that all the other blocks synchronized on the list can't execute in parallel.

If the list is shared by several threads, **all** its usages must be synchronized on the same monitor.

Answer (score 2):

If the "do something" directly or indirectly adds or removes something from `list` (except by using `it.remove()` or similar), then you'll get this exception. The synchronization won't stop it from happening in this case.

Comment: You should add "except by using it.remove() etc.".